# Problems with \\ in XeLaTeX when using Mac

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, windows, mac, arguments

I currently faced a problem with a XeTeX file I wrote using Windows 10 when I tried compiling it with MacOS Sierra 10.12.6. I had a .cls file containing following code snippet:

```
...
\newcommand{\cover}[9]{%
    \def\arga{#1}%
    \def\argb{#2}%
    \def\argc{#3}%
    \def\argd{#4}%
    \def\arge{#5}%
    \def\argf{#6}%
    \def\argg{#7}%
    \def\argh{#8}%
    \def\argi{#9}%
    \covercontinued
}

\newcommand{\covercontinued}[2]{%
\color{atwgrey}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{picture}
    (0,0)(0.625cm,18.75cm){%
        \put(0,0){%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0] at (-0.25,-1.55) {\picdims[height=18cm]{13.34cm}{18cm}{#2}\par};
                \node[anchor=north west] at (-0.6,0) {%
                    \includegraphics[scale=0.35,page=1]{graphicElements/posterlayout_blau.pdf}%
                };
                \node[anchor=north west] at (-0.4,-2.3) {%
                    \begin{minipage}[t][2.95cm]{6.5cm}
                        \raggedright{%
                            \color{atwgrey}\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont \arga{} | \argb{} | \argc \\%
                            \vfill %
                            \color{atwblue}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont \MakeUppercase{\argd} \\%
                            \fontsize{8.5pt}{12pt}\selectfont \ifdefempty{\arge}{}{\MakeUppercase{\arge} \\}%
                            \vfill %
                            \color{atwgrey}\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont \MakeUppercase{\argf} \\%
                            \fontsize{8.5pt}{11pt}\selectfont \argg %
                            \vfill %
                        }
                    \end{minipage}
                }; 
                \node[anchor=north west] at (6.5,-12.8) {%
                    \begin{minipage}[t][3cm]{6.5cm}
                        \raggedleft{%
                            \vfill %
                            \color{atwblue}
                            \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont \ifdefempty{\argh}{}{\MakeUppercase{\argh}\\}%
                            \fontsize{17pt}{20pt}\selectfont\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\argi}} \\ %
                            \ifcsempty{#1}{\vfill}{\vspace*{3pt}\fontsize{13pt}{13.5pt}\selectfont \MakeUppercase{#1}\vfill}%
                        }
                    \end{minipage}
                }; 
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
\end{picture}%
\color{black}%
}
...
```

When I used the .cls file with my .tex document and I put `\\` in one of the arguments, Windows handles it perfectly. If I compile the very same files with Mac, there is the following error:

```
! Use of \@icentercr doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def
l.18 {img/funny-cat}
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
...
```

The solution was to replace all occurences of `\\` by `\par`. That way, it works perfectly the way it should. I want to understand what is the problem here. I found out that the error usually only occurs when making mistakes of naming arguments, e.g. inserting numbers in the names. Since the error only occurs using Mac (while using texmaker/TeXLive), I doubt that this is the problem here.

Are there any additional restrictions for using arguments compared to Windows? Or are there other differences perhaps?

Comment: Can you please make a full example from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}` that shows the error? Do you *really* want an 11-argument macro?

Comment: you may get different behaviour on two machines but windows/mac will not be related to the problem, you will have different versions of some package, but as you have given no information about packages used or provided example code that can be run, it is hard to help at all.

Comment: note the form you use `(0.625cm,18.75cm)` with units in the coordinates requires a very recent latex (or the picture package)  so if you are not using `\usepackage{picture}` you will get errors if one machine has a latex older than 2020 release.